# Kendo AutoComplete Default Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, autocomplete, kendo-ui

## Need Value Already Set

I am using Kendo autocomplete to select an item from a list. I need to set the value of the text input field and make that actually use the value from the list.

Right now I am setting the text value of the input field to the value of the item in the table, though it is not actually using it as though you were to type it in and click on the auto-completed item.

Setting the default text :

```
IQueryable<StorageLocation> query = (from s in db.StorageLocations.Include("StorageLocationType") select s);
        DefaultStorageLocation = query.Count() != 1 ? "" : query.FirstOrDefault().TitleWithType;
```

Setting the value of the text box:

```
<input type="text" value="<%: Model.DefaultStorageLocation %>" name="StorageLocation" id="StorageLocation" originalname="StorageLocation" placeholder="" class="autoComplete" style="width: 158px;" />
```

My Kendo AutoComplete:

```
$('#StorageLocation' + rowID).kendoAutoComplete({
        dataTextField: 'title',
        dataValueField: 'id',
        minLength: 2,
        autoBind: false,
        select: function (e) {
            var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
            $('#StorageLocationID' + rowID).val(dataItem.id);
        },
        dataSource: {
            type: 'json',
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: function (opt) {
                        return '/Autocomplete/StorageLocations?searchText=' + opt.filter.filters[0].value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

So in short.

- I am setting the value of the text input
- Need it to actually use the value as if it were selected from autocomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller **searchResult** search query

```
storageLocation = (DefaultWarehouseForIA && !StorageLocation.IsNull()) ? StorageLocation.TitleWithType : "",
defaultStorageLocationID = (DefaultWarehouseForIA && DefaultStorageLocationID.ToLong() > 0) ? DefaultStorageLocationID : null
```

JS values being filled when another text field is filled in.

```
select: function (e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
    $('#StorageLocation' + rowID).val(dataItem.storageLocation);
    $('#StorageLocationID' + rowID).val(dataItem.defaultStorageLocationID);
}
```

At this point I have figured it out. Have it working.

So now the value is being auto filled when another text field is being filled in.
Explanation isn't too great here. But hey.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to auto-select the first value when there is only one. I think the `suggest` property will do what you're looking for: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete#configuration-suggest

Alternatively, try the `value` method: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete#methods-value

Comment: I went and tried suggest. It still requires the user to type something in before suggesting the rest.

Comment: That sounds right; looks like I read the documentation wrong. What about the `value` method?

Comment: This fills in the text fine, but still doesn't act as if it was selected from the autocomplete list. The validation I am using does not see it as a a value from the autocomplete list.